# Vue.js v-for element from $refs broken in watch function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With Vue.js 2.5.22 and FireFox 65.0. What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/r083hqgv/2/

A `v-for` element identified by a `:ref="x"` attribute doesn't work as expected in a `watch` function. I've also tried using `:id="x"` & `getElementById()`, and calling `setTimeout(..., 200)` within `$nextTick()`.

Code from the above fiddle:

```
<div id="app" style="position:relative">
  <h2>last element top: {{offset+''}}</h2>
  <button @click="add()">Add &amp; get top</button>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="a in list" :key="'r.'+a">
      <a @click.stop.prevent="get($event.target)" href="#"
         :ref="'r.'+a">get top {{'r.'+a}}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    offset: 0,
    last: 'unset',
    list: [],
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.last = 'r.'+ this.list.push(this.list.length+1);
      this.list = this.list.slice();
    },
    get: function(iEl) {
      this.offset = iEl.offsetTop;
      iEl.style = 'font-style:italic';
    }
  },
  watch: {
    list: function() {
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        var aEl = this.$refs[this.last];
        if (aEl) this.get(aEl);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced by the documentation ([$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)), `this.$refs["..."]` returns an array when `v-for` is used. Therefore, change

```
if (aEl) this.get(aEl);
```

to

```
if (aEl) this.get(aEl[0]);
```

Everything will work (I already tested it on your jsfiddle).

Comment: But alas not documented on the API page for `$refs` :-(

Any idea why `document.getElementById()` with `:id="x"` didn't work?

Comment: How did you use `document.getElementById()`? Cuz it's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wx4qvLu2/1/

Comment: In my actual app, there's a 2D array with `<template v-for...>` and other complications. I can't quickly reproduce it. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Happy to help @Liam

Comment: Refs in a loop are an array. Console.log this.refs in your watch funtion. You probably dont need a custom ref name for each item, just use the index.

Comment: In my actual app, we don't have the index of the next array item, we only have its ref name.

Comment: @Liam edit approved. And regarding what was said earlier, I'm interested to know more about the array and why only `refs` can be used, cuz I'm guessing you can probably 'transform' the array to sth else to get around that.

Comment: The actual-app's array is generated elsewhere; in fact we watch `'$root.x'`. When a new item is expected, we know its ref name but not where in the array it will land.

Comment: Okay, I see, I rarely use `$ref` unless I'm using frameworks like `Vuetify`, that's why I'm interested.